# Configuring Sublime Text 3 with XDebugger Client - Sublime XDebugger Window Has No Activity

Tags: php, debugging, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I configured the XDebug on `php.ini` and `phpinfo()` echos that it is active as well:

[image: XDebug]

Also I installed the XDebugger Client on Sublime Text 3 and configured the its user setting `Xdebug.sublime.settings` as follows:

```
{
    "path_mapping": {
        "/srv/www": "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    },
    "max_depth": 5
}
```

My files are located in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/toti` and the browser shows the errors inside the XDebug window on `http://localhost/toti/`, however the XDebug window on `sublime text 3` shows no activity whenever running the page in browser. Note that I added the breakpoints to the code as well.

[image]

[image]